# Char** arrays of string

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc

I tried to do a code that gets number from the user and create array of strings (`char**`) by the number but for some reason it didn't work and the code crashed. After inputting the strings, the code sorts the strings using `strcmp()` and then I want to print the whole array. Could anyone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LENGTH 20

int main(void)
{
    int players = 0,i=0,j=0;
    char switchString[LENGTH];
    printf("Hello user, Welcome to your basketball team!\nplease enter a number of players that plays in your team\n");
    scanf("%d", &players);
    char** team = (char**)malloc(players*sizeof(char));
    for (i = 0; i < players; i++)
    {
        *(team+i) = (char*)malloc(LENGTH*sizeof(char));
        printf("enter name of player %d\n",i+1);
        fgets(*(team+i), LENGTH, stdin);
        *(team+i)[strcspn(*(team+i), "\n")] = "\0";
    }
    for (i = 0; i <players; i++) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < players; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(team[j - 1], team[j]) > 0) 
            {
                strcpy(switchString, team[j-1]);
                strcpy(team[j-1], team[j]);
                strcpy(team[j], switchString);
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i <players; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < players; j++)
        {
            printf("%c",team[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    free(team);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `players*sizeof(char)` can't be right. I don't have the energy to look at the rest of the code.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Always check that the input functions have succeeded; check the return value from `fgets()`.  You allocate lots of chunks of memory but free only one; that means you leak memory — not yet a problem since you're crashing.  It's interesting that you switch from `*(team + i)` to `team[i]` notation.  Consistency is good in programming, and `team[i]` is probably the clearer choice.

Comment: `*(team+i)[strcspn(*(team+i), "\n")] = "\0";` This line is the winner of the daily SO obfuscated C contest, congratulations! Oh, and it also creates a fat memory leak, given that it even compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This memory allocation

```
char** team = (char**)malloc(players*sizeof(char));
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

is wrong. There shall be

```
char** team = (char**)malloc(players*sizeof(char *));
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This assignment

```
*(team+i)[strcspn(*(team+i), "\n")] = "\0";
^^^^^^^^^                             ^^^^
```

is also wrong

There shall be

```
( *(team+i) )[strcspn(*(team+i), "\n")] = '\0';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^                             ^^^^
```

Or you could just write

```
team[i][strcspn(team[i], "\n")] = '\0';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^
```

Also this loop

```
    for (j = 0; j < players; j++)
    {
        if (strcmp(team[j - 1], team[j]) > 0) 
        {
            strcpy(switchString, team[j-1]);
            strcpy(team[j-1], team[j]);
            strcpy(team[j], switchString);
        }
    }
```

also incorrect because when `j` is equal to 0 then in the if statement in expression `team[j - 1]` there is an attempt to access memory beyond the array.

The loop should look at least like

```
    for (j = 1; j < players; j++)
         ^^^^^
    {
        if (strcmp(team[j - 1], team[j]) > 0) 
        {
            strcpy(switchString, team[j-1]);
            strcpy(team[j-1], team[j]);
            strcpy(team[j], switchString);
        }
    }
```

And at last these loops are also nvalid

```
for (i = 0; i <players; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < players; j++)
    {
        printf("%c",team[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

because in the inner loop there are attempts to output characters after the terminating zero.

Just write

```
for (i = 0; i <players; i++)
{
    puts( team[i] );
}
```

Or you could write for example

```
for (i = 0; i <players; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; players[i][j] != '\0'; j++)
    {
        printf("%c",team[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

And at the end of the program you need to free the allocated memory.

For example

```
for (i = 0; i <players; i++)
{
    free( team[i] );
}
free( team );
```

Comment: thank you so much! you really helped me! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
char** team = (char**)malloc(players*sizeof(char));
```

(Allocate memory of `players` bytes)

Should be

```
char** team = malloc(players*sizeof(char*));
```

(Allocate memory to store  `players` pointers to character)

Comment: For maintainability reasons, among others, it's best to [not cast the results of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) and use `sizeof(*team)` instead of `sizeof(char*)`.

Comment: but it's still crashed

Answer (score 0):

Replace line

```
char** team = (char**)malloc(players*sizeof(char));
```

with

```
char** team = malloc(players*sizeof(char*));
int i;
for (i = 0; i < players; i++)
    team[i] = malloc(LENGTH*sizeof(char));
```

Comment: it's still crashed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have fixed the memory allocation for the main array of pointers, then the test in the inner loop like this:

```
if (strcmp(team[j - 1], team[j]) > 0)
```

is going to lead to unhappiness when `j` is equal to 0, as it is on the first iteration.  That's because you don't have an element with index `-1`. This is a major problem, even if it isn't the only remaining cause of your crash.

Answer (score 0):

There's a variety of ways to do this, and a variety of issues with the code given.

Here's a working example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LENGTH 20

int main(void)
{
    int players = 0;
    char switchString[LENGTH];
    printf("Hello user, welcome to your basketball team!\n"
           "Please enter the number of players on your team.\n");

    if (fscanf(stdin, "%d", &players) != 1 || players > 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error getting player count\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // Flush the input stream
    while (getchar() != '\n');

    char (*teams)[LENGTH];
    teams = malloc(players * sizeof(*teams));
    if (!teams)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating team array\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < players; ++i)
    {
        char *team = teams[i];
        printf("Enter the name of player %d: ", i+1);
        if (!fgets(team, LENGTH, stdin))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error getting name of player\n");
            free(team);
            return 1;
        }
        char *endline = strchr(team, '\n');
        if (endline)
            *endline = '\0';
    }

    // Bubble sort
    for (int i = 0; i < players; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < players; ++j)
        {
            if (strcmp(teams[j - 1], teams[j]) > 0)
            {
                strncpy(switchString, teams[j-1], LENGTH);
                strncpy(teams[j-1], teams[j], LENGTH);
                strncpy(teams[j], switchString, LENGTH);
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < players; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", teams[i]);
    }
    free(teams);
    return 0;
```

Let's go through this solution piece by piece.

```
if (fscanf(stdin, "%d", &players) != 1 || players > 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error getting player count\n");
    return 1;
}
// Flush the input stream
while (getchar() != '\n');
```

This will get the number of players and make sure that we the newline we gave [doesn't mess with the following inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7898516/1530134).

```
char (*teams)[LENGTH];
teams = malloc(players * sizeof(*teams));
if (!teams)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error creating team array\n");
    return 1;
}
```

This completely changes how we store teams.
Why do more `malloc`s than you have to?
This declares `teams` as a pointer to an array of `LENGTH`.
This means that when we `malloc`, we store all of the memory for the names next to each other, and `teams[0]` points to the `char *` of the first team, `teams[1]` points to the `char *` of the second team, and so on.

```
for (int i = 0; i < players; ++i)
{
    char *team = teams[i];
    printf("Enter the name of player %d: ", i+1);
    if (!fgets(team, LENGTH, stdin))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error getting name of player\n");
        free(team);
        return 1;
    }
    char *endline = strchr(team, '\n');
    if (endline)
        *endline = '\0';
}
```

Instead of using `*(team + i)` everywhere, the type of `teams` allows us to naturally refer to each element like an array of arrays.
We also do a check that `fgets` succeeds.
We also use `strchr` to remove the newline as it is clearer to read.

```
// Bubble sort
for (int i = 0; i < players; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < players; ++j)
    {
        if (strcmp(teams[j - 1], teams[j]) > 0)
        {
            strncpy(switchString, teams[j-1], LENGTH);
            strncpy(teams[j-1], teams[j], LENGTH);
            strncpy(teams[j], switchString, LENGTH);
        }
    }
}
```

We now use `strncpy` for safety. Bubble sort can also be made more efficient.

Notice that in the original code, `free` was only called for the array of pointers (`char **`), and not each `char *` pointer.